# SignalR client is not connecting to the hub after changing the client app's cookie name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, websocket, signalr

I have two MVC applications with authentication and authorization with an identity server. App1 has its default cookie name and app2 has a custom cookie name.

App2 is the client and App1 is the server which is the SignalR chatHub is defined. Problem is that the client app not connecting to the server app after changing the client app cookie name.

Without changing the cookie name and running on the incognito window the client is connecting to the server without any errors. This issue occurred only for the WebSocket. Any idea?

I have tried changing the connection URL and Cors configurations.